# Copying stack object in to new heap allocated

Tags: c++

Im trying to copy stack object in to new heap allocated, because stack objects are being destroyed by end of the scope. But information about the data i need for next frame (for my command system).

I'm not professional with copying raw memory, but i need to implement some kind of system.I have implemented one of the methods, but I am not sure that it will work at least 99 of the time. I wonder if I did it right or the code doesn't make sense.

First of all i create struct called `MemBlock`, where data and size are stored.

```cpp
struct MemBlock {
    void*  data  = nullptr;
    size_t size  = 0;
};
```

And then i've have a function `CopyMemBlockArray` that copied each of MemBlock in vector from stack to heap (a new allocated).

```cpp
void CopyMemBlockArray(const std::vector<MemBlock>& src, std::vector<MemBlock>* dst) {
        
        // Cannot copy because dst is null.
        if (!dst)
            return;

        for (auto& block : src) {

            // Alocate memory for copied block.
            MemBlock copiedBlock;
            copiedBlock.size = block.size;
            copiedBlock.data = malloc(block.size);

            // Copy block into allocated memory block.
            memcpy(copiedBlock.data, block.data, block.size);
            dst->push_back(copiedBlock);
        }
    }
```

And here example of usage:

```cpp
void MyFoo() {
    int                value  = 1;
    unsigned long long value2 = 3242424;

    // Copy
    std::vector<MemBlock> argv;
    argv.push_back({ &value,  sizeof(int) });
    argv.push_back({ &value2, sizeof(unsigned long long) });

    std::vector<MemBlock>* copiedArgv = new std::vector<MemBlock>();
    CopyMemBlockArray(argv, &copiedArgv);

    // Skip few frames (do something with this values in process)

    // Free
    int*                pValue  = (int*) copiedArgv [0].data;
    unsigned long long* pvalue2 = (unsigned long long*) copiedArgv [1].data;
    free(pValue);
    free(pValue2);
}
```

It seems to be working fine with numbers, but what if by stack object is have other objects,
or pointers, free function not call destructor for them. But i cannot use `delete` because data is void*, type is not defined (for numbers its works, but for custom types, crash).

So for example i have:

```
struct A {
   int i = 5;
   std::string text = "some text"; // With strings also can be problem because inderline (char* will be deleted from original stack object on copy it will be empty)
}

struct B {
   MyObject customObject;
   A a;
}
```

And destructor will call for each of this structs if copy it with `CopyMemBlockArray` and then try use `free()` on them?

Comment: You should use `std::any` instead of trying to implement the same thing: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Comment: OT: I don't think there are many cases where dynamically allocating a `vector` by `new` is reasonable.

Comment: @MattTimmermans You mean that i can just replace vector of MemBlock by std::any and objects will still remain even if it stack allocated?

Comment: Hmmm. actually, no.  I can't figure out what problem you really have.

Comment: It's not only about missing destructor calls in `free`. You cannot use `memcpy` for anything other than trivially-copyable objects. So once the objects are not trivially-copyable, you cannot copy them this way.

Comment: There is never a valid reason to use `malloc` and `free` in C++. That's for C, not C++.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I just need a save stack objects or pointers in to new allocated pointer with the same data, to reuse it later. For example stack object `A`, contains some info but by end of the scope it frees, and when my `CommandManager` execute command later on next frame, i cannot get that same stack object with the same data.

Comment: The thing is that `std::any` has already solved the problem of storing *any* type, copy and assign it, and then get the original value back. Why implement that again?

Comment: If you want to copy any object in C++, then use direct-initialization and provide the source object as the initialization expression. In your case, in the context of the `new` expression. Using `memcpy` and `malloc` does not make any sense here.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes, i tried that but problem it is because a `Command `can accept multiple arguments with multiple types so i cannot store them im `std::vector`. I can use a template but its also risky for my code base.

Comment: I think most excited features that comes with C++ is FileSystem and this Any thing. Its perfectly work with stack objects, pointers, const char*, std::string. Thanks, never heard about it before.

Comment: @Kenny I would really like to see some reasonable use case for `std::any`. Yes, you can put objects of different types into `any` and store them to the same vector. But once you want to use them then, you need to know the stored type for `any_cast`. And if you somehow remember this stored type out of some particular set, `std::variant` is much better choice.

Comment: @DanielLangr `variant` requires you to enumerate all possible types in advance, which isn't possible in generic code.

Comment: @DanielLangr For example for my `Command System`, that allows put arguments of different types and data, that at the end of `rendering` frame or `rendering` scope freed. And of course this data can be unique so i technically copy pointers or stack object in to another heap objects or now with this `std::any`. And when command is executed later, this arguments placed there in the specific order. So if arguments will be in different order from initialize command `std::any_cast()`, gives a runtime error or `std::bad_any_cast`. So is should be safe.

Comment: @DanielLangr Of course its only one usage of `std::any`, it depends on the type of task. As for `std::variant`, I've never used it, so I'm not particularly familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Generally, you can instantiate an object at any place in memory with placement new. So if you have the memory where you can "place" the object, you can use placement new to call the constructor of your object with a this pointer pointing to that memory.

But this would not make sense at all. So if you need the objects on the heap because they are destroyed after your function exits you simply create them on the heap (with new) directly, without first creating them on the stack. So you can then go ahead and copy the pointer or smart pointer respectively anywhere you want.

Another thing that might cause issues going this memcpy approach is alignment. Objects are aligned in some way so they need to be placed at a specific boundary.

Never (!) memcpy objects (I mean instances of user defined types)! This opens the door to hell. C++ has builtin semantics for this (copy constructor, copy assignment operator).

If you really really really need to store an object at a specific address use placement new. But be aware that the memory you use must be aligned properly. Here I don't see any reason to this though.

Comment: "Never (!) memcpy objects" why never? It does not open any door when the type is trivially copyable.

Comment: "I mean instances of user defined types" - because they might manage resources. 2nd reason: This is about C++, you can copy objects naturally and that way you're sure you're not messing up things.

Comment: I am talking about C++ as well where trivially copyable types (user defined or not) can be copied via `memcpy` without messing up anything

Comment: Why would you do that instead of simply assigning values? There is just NO reason to do so and yes, `memcpy` with user defined types managing resources DOES open the door to hell!

Comment: sorry but you do not get the point. Suppose you receive a stream of bytes from the wire. Then a type `T` that is trivially copyable (look it up if you dont know what it means) can safely be copied into a `T` via `memcpy`. You cannot use `operator=` when you only have the bytes that make up the object. This does not open the door to hell.

Comment: trivially copyable types typically do not manage resources, hence saying that a type that manages a resource should not be copied via `memcpy` is a moot point.

Comment: all I am saying is that "Never use `memcpy`" is to strong. Its not "never"

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable

Comment: If you want to create an object from a stream over the wire with memcpy - have fun (not to mention endianness)! As I pointed out, there is placement new (its c++ and not c). If you have a managed pointer in your instance and you copy with memcpy you are in trouble - a pointer is trivially copyable by the way. Just stop doing c with classes. It is perfectly fine to use c. There are so many pitfalls unexperienced people fall into, this is one of those.

Comment: this has nothing to do with "c with classes". I do not want to "create" an object , I want to copy from a stream of bytes to an already existing object. placement new is not doing that, but `memcpy` does (still, provided the type is trivially copyable). You still didnt explain what the pitfall is. A trivially copyable type can be `memcpy`ied by definition, thats what makes it trivially copyable

Comment: So point to your already existing object:
```cpp
const MyThing* myThing = reinterpret_cast<const MyThing*> (myPtrToMyThingThatAlreadyExists);
new (myPtrToWhereINeedToBeCreated) MyThing {*myThing}; // copy ctor
```